# Integral measure quantum fields

Tags: integration, vectors, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

In many physics books (especially QFT), the integral measure for a quantum field is written down as

\begin{equation}
\phi(x)=\int\frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}....
\end{equation}

It is a summation over the continuous momentum variable in 3 (Euclidian) space. However, in these same books, 3-vectors are distinguished by bold Latin letters $\bf{p}$. shouldn't the integral measure instead be written as
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{d^{3}\bf{p}}{(2\pi)^{3}}?
\end{equation}

But then, it could imply that the quantum field $\phi(x)$ is a vector quantity (which isn't). For example in Stoke's divergence theorem, the integral $d\bf{a}$ is a 3-vector  quantity (area element with orientation). what is the best way out of this confusion, i.e. what is the correct mathematical way to express the integral measure in quantum fields?

Comment: The way it's currently written, it just seems to be 3-dimensional Lebesgue measure (modulo some constants). I've seen a villion variants on how to express this fact; that's all just notation. Just keep in mind it's 3D Lebesgue measure (i.e the usual volume integral type thing) and you'll be fine.

Comment: The word 'Lebesgue' is frightening for physicists since most of us don't know what it means. In any case, if both are fine then that answers my question. Thanks